# rpmbuild Requires(post) does not work as expected, require a local package

Tags: dependencies, rpm, yum, rpmbuild, requires

My understanding from everything I read about spec files is that the Requires(post) statement would make it so any library following it would not be required until after the installation has finished. It doesn't seem to be the case. Am I misunderstanding this command?

My main objective is to download another rpm in the %pre section and then require it later so that it will install it from the local copy. If there is another way to go about this than what I am doing, I would greatly appreciate the help?

Comment: If the package is not available when the transaction begins I don't believe you can *make* it available during the transaction. Everything else about the question aside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Requires(post)` tag tells rpm that your package requires that package *to be installed* before the `%post` scriplet of your RPM can run (presumably because you depend on a file from that package in your `%post` scriptlet in some fashion).

This is used for ordering of package installation within a transaction.

As far as I am aware (and I believe the verbose debug output from yum will confirm this) the full set of required package information is assembled *before* the transaction begins not willy-nilly as packages are installed.

So, as I indicated in my comment, everything else here aside I don't believe you can **make** a package available for the transaction from *within* the transaction.

Comment: Etan, thanks for the answers. So I tried to instead make my requires statement something like "Requires: http:....../package.rpm" and give it the whole address, this also failed. Would there be a way to run a yum-config-manager --add-repo command before my requires section is run?

Comment: @MarkS You don't have a "requires section". You have `Requires` entries in your spec which get encoded in the header of the generated RPM. Yum/rpm then uses those to find appropriate packages and construct a transaction that works. So no, you can't do *anything* at that point in time. You are just data, not code, at that point. If you need an external repository you get to create a `myrepo-release`-style package (like `redhat-release` or `centos-release` or `epel-release` and have people install that first, whicih is a good idea anyway since then they get your GPG keys too).

Answer (score 0):

You can't install another RPM from an RPM. The DB will be locked. Put them both in the same yum repository, and then `yum` will ensure they are both installed if you have them require each other.